# Is there any way to get the eldest available offset for a kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, offset, spring-kafka

I have a requirement where I am storing information of the offset till which system has read the data. So next time when the system starts reading data again from kafka I need to read data in between the older offset that we have in the system to the newest offset. But the older offset might be invalid due to kafka retention policy. So if we specify older offset in kafka consumer what will be the behavior? Also is there any way we could get the oldest offset value for a particular topic/offset so that we start reading from it?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the way you configure your consumer. Specifically, the `auto.offset.rest` parameter. If you set it to `earliest` your consumer will start consuming from the earliest available offset (if the offset you try to consume from is not valid).
This way you don't need to find the oldest offset value, since the consumer behaves like I described.
You can find more details [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#:%7E:text=Second%2C%20use%20auto.,%E2%80%9D%20offset%20(the%20default)).

Comment: `auto.offset.reset` only applies to new consumer `group.id`s. You have to seek if the consumer has already committed an offset.

Comment: @GaryRussell As far as I understand the description for `auto.offset.reset` it specifically also applies for the cases where an offset was deleted due to retention: "What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted)"

Comment: That is true, but these days that is rare - the algorithm was changed (in 2.1.0 IIRC) such that the group is not removed (by default) unless 7 days has elapsed since the last consumer left the group (the retention time previously started from the last offset commit time). In any case, from Kafka's perspective, such a consumer is considered a new consumer. It is, however, more correct to express it your way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply perform `seekToBeginning` during start up.

Implement `ConsumerSeekAware` or, preferably, extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`.

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.0/reference/html/#seek).

Just call `seekToBeginning` in `onPartitionsAssigned`.