# How do I set up a @KafkaListener to always reset on startup?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka topic which receives messages like

```
Kafka key: serverId
value: server host name
```

I just need the latest ones for each serverId so it's a very small segment size and log compaction is enabled.  So what I do is the following

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = SERVERS_KAFKA_TOPIC, id = "#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}",
  properties = {
    "spring.json.key.default.type=java.lang.String",
    "spring.json.value.default.type=java.lang.String"
  })
  public void registerServer(
    @Payload(required = false) String serverHostName
    ) {
```

Basically I create a new consumer group per listener because I am going by the assumption that if it is the same consumer group, it will continue where the last one left off and the state across a replica set will not be what I am expecting.

Of course it sort of makes the list of consumer groups very annoying.  I was wondering short of creating another shared service like Redis to store the data since I can't really store using Redis as the data that I build from the message is a GRPC client, can I configure the listener to always start from the beginning and ignore the other consumers in the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `seekToBeginning()` method that gets provided by `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` didn't seek from beginning when I tried.  However, this code did work

```
/**
 * Reset to the beginning
 *
 * <p>{@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(
        @NotNull Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments,
        @NotNull ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {

    assignments.keySet().stream()
            .filter(topicPartition -> SERVERS_KAFKA_TOPIC.equals(topicPartition.topic()))
            .forEach(
                    topicPartition ->
                            callback.seekToBeginning(
                                    topicPartition.topic(), topicPartition.partition()));
}
```

Also I needed it for a specific topic not for ALL topics as such the approach I found also limits it to a specific topic.

Answer (score 1):

Make your listener bean extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` and in `onPartitionsAssigned`, call `seekToBeginning()`.

```
    /**
     * Seek all assigned partitions to the beginning.
     * @since 2.6
     */
    public void seekToBeginning() {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/

[How to implement ConsumerSeekAware in Spring-kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663661/how-to-implement-consumerseekaware-in-spring-kafka/63673081#63673081)

[Is there any way to get the eldest available offset for a kafka topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63799075/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-eldest-available-offset-for-a-kafka-topic/63799236#63799236)

Comment: Would that force all existing consumer instances to reset as well?  Which would be a bit problematic if they already have their connections established.

Comment: If the other consumers are in different groups, they will be unaffected. If they are in the same group, they will have different partitions assigned so, again, they will be unaffected.

Comment: Actually it does not appear to work. it seeks but the KafkaListener does not call.  In my case for development, only single server and only one message was sent.

Comment: That doesn't make sense; I do it all the time; post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace so I can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I think it's because you didn't write a code example so from your commend we just called seek to  beginning.